# ChromeOption "w3c" false - nightwatch js

Tags: nightwatch

I am new to the selenium world, I am starting to use nightwatchjs by following an online course. I had the issue for which I added a w3c : false to chrome options. I didn't exactly understand what is the issue and why I have to turn off the w3c to be able to run my test.

Could you please clarify to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is a little barebones and it would be great if you could expand upon it by mentioning what you tried and what you found on the internet. Personally I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457780/9363973) very extensive SO answer written by a test automation engineer at Selenium. And as I understand it after briefly skimming it they say that it should be fixed in Chrome Driver v75.0 and upwards

Comment: Refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502302/typeerror-err-unescaped-characters-when-running-nightwatchjs-test

Answer (score 0):

If W3c= false it will handle windows switch handler in new tabs in same browsers with Dynamic URL's.

If W3c= True ,I have faced issues in nightwatch.js ,during windows switch handler in  same browser new tabs,  W2c capability not able to identify the windows switch handle if the URL generated in new tab is dynamic.